# Gradle build: Execution failed for task ':app:lint'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I'm using Android Studio 2.0 and I was trying to running my program when something strange happened. I ran the build command of the gradle and I got this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.197 secs
Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...
10:41:28: External task execution finished 'build'.
```

And so... What the hell is that? I'm supposed to do to solve this problem adding the code to the gradle.build, but the question is: **why I got this error message?**

Please save me guys!

Comment: Are you building in release?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what do you mean with "build in release"... Could you be more specific?

Comment: Are you using the build type "Debug" or "Release" ?

Comment: I'm building in debug mode

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Add this in your `app/build.gradle` file

```
android {
    //...
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: I got that, but I was looking for the cause of the error... Why would it appear?

Comment: For further viewers, make sure you're referencing the right `build.gradle` *within* your project - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250493/could-not-find-method-android-for-arguments

Comment: How about if a warning message, "Access is denied" pop out when I try t add this code into build.gradle.?

Comment: There are many `build.gradle`s in RN and, as the last answer specifies, use `build.gradle(Module: app)`.

Comment: Is there a command-line switch to act like temporarily  `abortOnError=false` without permanently adding it to the `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I wrote in build.gradle file. but Could not find method android() for arguments [build_9bspgiibcb79q5zrs1id49jgw$_run_closure2@4797b8b] on root project 'kazoemon' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: It is not a good solution. Sometimes, it causes real issues in release apk.

Comment: How to do this in gradle .kts?

Answer (score 29):

1. Switch to project view
2. Then, project/app/build/reports/lint-results
3. Now, you will find the lint-result files in two formats - 1) xml and 2) html.

You can view these files as is. However, I find viewing the lint results in a browser to be easy on the eyes. Just right-click on the html file and choose view in browser.

It opens up like the image below in my Chrome browser.

[image: Screenshot of lint results]

Comment: Rather than ignoring. This is the right way, to fix.

Comment: This one is good, I never really visit build folder that much before now I will.

Comment: Yep. In my case it was in the `project/app/build/reports/lint-results-debug` file though.

Answer (score 25):

You have some lint issues while you are bulding the app module.

You can find all issues found in the report generated in `Project\module\build\outputs`.
Here you will find the html file and the xml file with the lint report.

Using this script in the `app\build.gradle`

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

you can **disable** the block but it **is not the best practice**.
You should analyze the lint report to solve each point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the report. But why aren't those warnings integrated into Android Studio? I thought this IDE is so much better than ADT.

Comment: You should specify that the short script addition you advice, belongs to the Module:app part of build.gradle.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti
You are right. I changed my mind soon after, but it was late already :\
If you'd edit ur answer i'll be able again to cancel my down vote :)

Answer (score 10):

I think it's better to find the errors rather than ignoring them.

try this:

In Gradle Console find "**Wrote HTML report to file**", open the indicated HTML file and you will find a lint report

Go to your errors and fix them

[image: HTML lint report]

Answer (score 3):

Your **build.gradle(Module: app)** should include

---

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 3):

If the `abortOnError false` does not work, the Flutter version 2.5.1 recommend using the following arguments in the lintOptions:

```
android{
    ...
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `gradle build -i` instead of just `gradle build`.  There will be lots more output than usual.  Some of it will look like this:

```
> Task :project-name:lint FAILED
Putting task artifact state for task ':project-name:lint' into context took 0.0 secs.
Up-to-date check for task ':project-name:lint' took 0.0 secs. It is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Ran lint on variant release: 333 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 333 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///some/path/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///some/pahth/lint-results.xml

:project-name:lint (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 1.756 secs.
```

Check out `/some/path/lint-results.html` to see why lint failed.  Once those errors are fixed, your build will complete smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error `Execution failed for task ':app:lintVital[myBuildVariant]'` and a nullpointer error. It happened after switching branches and the thing that helped for me was to do a *Build -> Clean Project*

Answer (score 0):

Only add this code in build gradle:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

That should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you face this issue do not add a linter disabler to your gradle,
This is an access error issue,I faced that on react-native after using sudo command for a few command,
Just reset your code access and then release again
For example the mac

`sudo chmod -R 777 <project-root-folder-name>`

If it remains use

```
preBuild.doFirst { 
ant.replaceregexp(
    match:'Bad gradle', 
    replace:'Correct one', 
    flags:'g', 
    byline:true
) { 
    fileset(
        dir: 'Where to search', 
        includes: '*.java'
    ) 
} 
}
```

So you can fix error before release if exists in that library

Answer (score 0):

The new lint way is like so

```
android {
    lint {
        isAbortOnError = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to disable the lint entirely in debug and release builds. P.S. It is not recommended to disable the lint in release build.

Add below line in gradle.properties

```
gradle=build -x lint -x lintVitalRelease
```