# Could not find method android() for arguments in Android Studio 2.2 Windows 7 32bit

Tags: android-studio

I am new to Android Studio. While trying to build first android app I got stuck with this issue.

See the attached screen-shot

[my-application-screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McTGM.jpg)

Comment: Do not put screen shot of your IDE. Please copy and paste the code. and ask question.

Answer (score 0):

I found something similar already asked, I dont know if it is a duplicate but have a look at this link, it might be the solution. It looks like something with the Gradle version or build you are using.

[Could not find method android() for arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250493/could-not-find-method-android-for-arguments)