# how to fix mixed versions - error in build.gradle (Module:app) implementations (android studio)

Tags: android

I'm building a simple app, and my build.gradle (Module App) has all the default code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gr.aegean.icsd.samossellbuy"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' // line 23
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
```

**When i compile and run the app into the emulator it crashes immediately**

---

- *Error Message line 23*:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.1.0, 25.3.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.

I'm completly new in Android Studio , I tried to be as much detailed as i could.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: you are missing  buildToolsVersion "26.0.0" in your gradle

Comment: place it after compileSdkVersion

Comment: @vikaskumar i did but it gave me an error this time

Comment: phill i hope have posted full gradle file from app folder, because buildToolsVersion is missing and the error you are pointing seems to be ok. can you post the error you are getting now after build tool version update

Comment: its the module app and yes its the whole one

Comment: you are getting the same error or its the same new one ?

Comment: i get the following: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] on object type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.

Comment: i have posted a answer please check if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `implementation` to `compile`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "gr.aegean.icsd.samossellbuy"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' // line 23
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    }
```

Comment: i get the following error: couldn't find method android() for arguements , on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Comment: the app when i run the emulator still crashes:/

Comment: I hope you are not making changes in top-level build.gradle instead it should be in module level build.gradle

Comment: see detailed about the problem here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019584/could-not-find-method-android-for-arguments-org-gradle-api-project

Comment: are you able to compile your project or getting error while running on device. please post logcat of new error

Comment: i dont get an error, the application when the emulator just crashes

Answer (score 0):

This is because the library has not been updated to use the new support libraries Update Android Studio -> Check For Update