# Could not find method android() for arguments [] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gradle

I get this error when building the app. I don't even know what the issue is. I'll post the the full error message and the code where the issue should be.

```
* Where:
```

Script 'C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 73

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Could not find method android() for arguments [flutter_3xtlcf8y4k96s78jza8a827pu$_run_closure1@50ef998a] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Here below you'll find the flutter.gradle file line 73 where the error supposed to be.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        /* When bumping, also update ndkVersion above. */
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
    }
}


android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Line 73 starts with `android {`

The android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.20'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

}

The app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
compileSdkVersion 32

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.santosenoque.cabdriver"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

```
flutter {
source '../..'
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk11:$kotlin_version"
```

}

Comment: try to remove dependency line by line, and why you use signingConfig from debug? enable 'InvalidPackage', jcenter() is not working now

Comment: Check out this answer. Hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53023651