# Flutter APK Build on Mac

Tags: flutter

I'm getting this error while trying to build a flutter apk

[image: Error message]

[image: Build gradle]

I want to be able to build a flutter apk app on mac.

I'm getting this error while trying to build a flutter apk.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37252114/11891580

Comment: didn't worked on my end

Comment: Give as the full code of you gradle file!